# Из fragment1 перейти fragment2, по нажатию на ListView

Tags: android, java

из fragment1 перейти fragment2, по нажатию на ListView, вот пробую делать. он выдает ошибку, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0... в общем правильно ли я делаю? можно еще ссылку на пример какой нибудь?

[image]

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
ImageView ivIcon;
TextView tvItemName;
ListView lvMain;;
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

public static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
public static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";

List<DrawerItem> dataList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_two, container,
            false);
    lvMain = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity(), R.array.myTask,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Bundle args = new Bundle();             
            switch (position) {
            case 0:                
                toastMtethod("1");                  
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                args.putString(Fragment2.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(position)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(position)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 1:
                toastMtethod("2");
                break;

            case 2:
                toastMtethod("3");
                break;
            }}
    });
    return view;
}

void toastMtethod(String text) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас инициализируется

```
dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
```

а затем берётся по индексу

```
dataList.get(position)
```

при этом список пустой...поэтому и ошибка